# How do you send arguments to a generator function using tf.data.Dataset.from_generator()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I would like to create a number of `tf.data.Dataset` using the `from_generator()` function. I would like to send an argument to the generator function (`raw_data_gen`).  The idea is that the generator function will yield different data depending on the argument sent. In this way I would like `raw_data_gen` to be able to provide either training, validation or test data.

```
training_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(raw_data_gen, (tf.float32, tf.uint8), ([None, 1], [None]), args=([1]))

validation_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(raw_data_gen, (tf.float32, tf.uint8), ([None, 1], [None]), args=([2]))

test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(raw_data_gen, (tf.float32, tf.uint8), ([None, 1], [None]), args=([3]))
```

The error message I get when I try to call `from_generator()` in this way is:

```
TypeError: from_generator() got an unexpected keyword argument 'args'
```

Here is the `raw_data_gen` function although I'm not sure if you will need this as my hunch is that the problem is with the call of `from_generator()`:

```
def raw_data_gen(train_val_or_test):

    if train_val_or_test == 1:        
        #For every filename collected in the list
        for filename, lab in training_filepath_label_dict.items():
            raw_data, samplerate = soundfile.read(filename)
            try: #assume the audio is stereo, ready to be sliced
                raw_data = raw_data[:,0] #raw_data is a np.array, just take first channel with slice
            except IndexError:
                pass #this must be mono audio
            yield raw_data, lab

    elif train_val_or_test == 2:
        #For every filename collected in the list
        for filename, lab in validation_filepath_label_dict.items():
            raw_data, samplerate = soundfile.read(filename)
            try: #assume the audio is stereo, ready to be sliced
                raw_data = raw_data[:,0] #raw_data is a np.array, just take first channel with slice
            except IndexError:
                pass #this must be mono audio
            yield raw_data, lab

    elif train_val_or_test == 3:
        #For every filename collected in the list
        for filename, lab in test_filepath_label_dict.items():
            raw_data, samplerate = soundfile.read(filename)
            try: #assume the audio is stereo, ready to be sliced
                raw_data = raw_data[:,0] #raw_data is a np.array, just take first channel with slice
            except IndexError:
                pass #this must be mono audio
            yield raw_data, lab

    else:
        print("generator function called with an argument not in [1, 2, 3]")
        raise ValueError()
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to define a new function based on `raw_data_gen` that doesn't take any arguments. You can use the `lambda` keyword to do this.

```
training_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(lambda: raw_data_gen(train_val_or_test=1), (tf.float32, tf.uint8), ([None, 1], [None]))
...
```

Now, we are passing a function to `from_generator` that doesn't take any arguments, but that will simply act as `raw_data_gen` with the argument set to 1. You can use the same scheme for the validation and test sets, passing 2 and 3 respectively.

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you very much. Is this a current bug that from_generator() cannot take arguments? Or have I just misunderstood the documentation?

Comment: Oh right, I forgot that they added the `args` thing. This is a very recent update though, apparently introduced in 1.9. Maybe you are using an outdated version of Tensorflow?

Comment: Damn, you're right. I am using one version and reading documentation for another... Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

For Tensorflow 2.4:

```
training_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
     raw_data_gen, 
     args=(1), 
     output_types=(tf.float32, tf.uint8), 
     output_shapes=([None, 1], [None]))
```

Comment: I've encountered an issue with this solution - the args were converted to Bytes-like object