# Keras Generator to tf.data.Dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am working with the Mask RCNN keras implementation but the data generator hard locks on my systems when using `use_multiprocessing=True`. The data generator runs fine in single thread. I am trying to convert the data generator to a `tf.data.Dataset` as recommended by tensorflow. I have no idea how to do this and have been unable to find any documentation on this.

Mask RCNN data generator:

```
class DataGenerator(KU.Sequence):
    """An iterable that returns images and corresponding target class ids,
        bounding box deltas, and masks. It inherits from keras.utils.Sequence to avoid data redundancy
        when multiprocessing=True.

        dataset: The Dataset object to pick data from
        config: The model config object
        shuffle: If True, shuffles the samples before every epoch
        augmentation: Optional. An imgaug (https://github.com/aleju/imgaug) augmentation.
            For example, passing imgaug.augmenters.Fliplr(0.5) flips images
            right/left 50% of the time.
        random_rois: If > 0 then generate proposals to be used to train the
                     network classifier and mask heads. Useful if training
                     the Mask RCNN part without the RPN.
        detection_targets: If True, generate detection targets (class IDs, bbox
            deltas, and masks). Typically for debugging or visualizations because
            in trainig detection targets are generated by DetectionTargetLayer.

        Returns a Python iterable. Upon calling __getitem__() on it, the
        iterable returns two lists, inputs and outputs. The contents
        of the lists differ depending on the received arguments:
        inputs list:
        - images: [batch, H, W, C]
        - image_meta: [batch, (meta data)] Image details. See compose_image_meta()
        - rpn_match: [batch, N] Integer (1=positive anchor, -1=negative, 0=neutral)
        - rpn_bbox: [batch, N, (dy, dx, log(dh), log(dw))] Anchor bbox deltas.
        - gt_class_ids: [batch, MAX_GT_INSTANCES] Integer class IDs
        - gt_boxes: [batch, MAX_GT_INSTANCES, (y1, x1, y2, x2)]
        - gt_masks: [batch, height, width, MAX_GT_INSTANCES]. The height and width
                    are those of the image unless use_mini_mask is True, in which
                    case they are defined in MINI_MASK_SHAPE.

        outputs list: Usually empty in regular training. But if detection_targets
            is True then the outputs list contains target class_ids, bbox deltas,
            and masks.
        """

    def __init__(self, dataset, config, shuffle=True, augmentation=None,
                 random_rois=0, detection_targets=False):

        self.image_ids = np.copy(dataset.image_ids)
        self.dataset = dataset
        self.config = config

        # Anchors
        # [anchor_count, (y1, x1, y2, x2)]
        self.backbone_shapes = compute_backbone_shapes(config, config.IMAGE_SHAPE)
        self.anchors = utils.generate_pyramid_anchors(config.RPN_ANCHOR_SCALES,
                                                      config.RPN_ANCHOR_RATIOS,
                                                      self.backbone_shapes,
                                                      config.BACKBONE_STRIDES,
                                                      config.RPN_ANCHOR_STRIDE)

        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.augmentation = augmentation
        self.random_rois = random_rois
        self.batch_size = self.config.BATCH_SIZE
        self.detection_targets = detection_targets

    def __len__(self):
        return int(np.ceil(len(self.image_ids) / float(self.batch_size)))

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        b = 0
        image_index = -1
        while b < self.batch_size:
            
            # Increment index to pick next image. Shuffle if at the start of an epoch.
            image_index = (image_index + 1) % len(self.image_ids)

            if self.shuffle and image_index == 0:
                np.random.shuffle(self.image_ids)

            # Get GT bounding boxes and masks for image.
            image_id = self.image_ids[image_index]
            image, image_meta, gt_class_ids, gt_boxes, gt_masks = \
                load_image_gt(self.dataset, self.config, image_id,
                              augmentation=self.augmentation)

            # Skip images that have no instances. This can happen in cases
            # where we train on a subset of classes and the image doesn't
            # have any of the classes we care about.
            if not np.any(gt_class_ids > 0):
                continue

            # RPN Targets
            rpn_match, rpn_bbox = build_rpn_targets(image.shape, self.anchors,
                                                    gt_class_ids, gt_boxes, self.config)

            # Mask R-CNN Targets
            if self.random_rois:
                rpn_rois = generate_random_rois(
                    image.shape, self.random_rois, gt_class_ids, gt_boxes)
                if self.detection_targets:
                    rois, mrcnn_class_ids, mrcnn_bbox, mrcnn_mask = \
                        build_detection_targets(
                            rpn_rois, gt_class_ids, gt_boxes, gt_masks, self.config)

            # Init batch arrays
            if b == 0:
                batch_image_meta = np.zeros((self.batch_size,) + image_meta.shape, dtype=image_meta.dtype)
                batch_rpn_match = np.zeros([self.batch_size, self.anchors.shape[0], 1], dtype=rpn_match.dtype)
                batch_rpn_bbox = np.zeros([self.batch_size, self.config.RPN_TRAIN_ANCHORS_PER_IMAGE, 4], dtype=rpn_bbox.dtype)
                batch_images = np.zeros((self.batch_size,) + image.shape, dtype=np.float32)
                batch_gt_class_ids = np.zeros((self.batch_size, self.config.MAX_GT_INSTANCES), dtype=np.int32)
                batch_gt_boxes = np.zeros((self.batch_size, self.config.MAX_GT_INSTANCES, 4), dtype=np.int32)
                batch_gt_masks = np.zeros((self.batch_size, gt_masks.shape[0], gt_masks.shape[1],self.config.MAX_GT_INSTANCES), dtype=gt_masks.dtype)
                if self.random_rois:
                    batch_rpn_rois = np.zeros((self.batch_size, rpn_rois.shape[0], 4), dtype=rpn_rois.dtype)
                    if self.detection_targets:
                        batch_rois = np.zeros((self.batch_size,) + rois.shape, dtype=rois.dtype)
                        batch_mrcnn_class_ids = np.zeros((self.batch_size,) + mrcnn_class_ids.shape, dtype=mrcnn_class_ids.dtype)
                        batch_mrcnn_bbox = np.zeros((self.batch_size,) + mrcnn_bbox.shape, dtype=mrcnn_bbox.dtype)
                        batch_mrcnn_mask = np.zeros((self.batch_size,) + mrcnn_mask.shape, dtype=mrcnn_mask.dtype)

            # If more instances than fits in the array, sub-sample from them.
            if gt_boxes.shape[0] > self.config.MAX_GT_INSTANCES:
                ids = np.random.choice(
                    np.arange(gt_boxes.shape[0]), self.config.MAX_GT_INSTANCES, replace=False)
                gt_class_ids = gt_class_ids[ids]
                gt_boxes = gt_boxes[ids]
                gt_masks = gt_masks[:, :, ids]

            # Add to batch
            batch_image_meta[b] = image_meta
            batch_rpn_match[b] = rpn_match[:, np.newaxis]
            batch_rpn_bbox[b] = rpn_bbox
            batch_images[b] = mold_image(image.astype(np.float32), self.config)
            batch_gt_class_ids[b, :gt_class_ids.shape[0]] = gt_class_ids
            batch_gt_boxes[b, :gt_boxes.shape[0]] = gt_boxes
            batch_gt_masks[b, :, :, :gt_masks.shape[-1]] = gt_masks
            if self.random_rois:
                batch_rpn_rois[b] = rpn_rois
                if self.detection_targets:
                    batch_rois[b] = rois
                    batch_mrcnn_class_ids[b] = mrcnn_class_ids
                    batch_mrcnn_bbox[b] = mrcnn_bbox
                    batch_mrcnn_mask[b] = mrcnn_mask
            b += 1

        inputs = [batch_images, batch_image_meta, batch_rpn_match, batch_rpn_bbox,
                  batch_gt_class_ids, batch_gt_boxes, batch_gt_masks]
        outputs = []

        if self.random_rois:
            inputs.extend([batch_rpn_rois])
            if self.detection_targets:
                inputs.extend([batch_rois])
                # Keras requires that output and targets have the same number of dimensions
                batch_mrcnn_class_ids = np.expand_dims(
                    batch_mrcnn_class_ids, -1)
                outputs.extend(
                    [batch_mrcnn_class_ids, batch_mrcnn_bbox, batch_mrcnn_mask])

        return inputs, outputs
```

I have tried to use the `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator()` however it requires the `output_types=` argument and the Mask RCNN outputs a number of lists, I can not figure out how to define `output_types=`.

I am using `python3.7`, `keras==2.2.5`, `tensorflow==2.2.0`

Comment: Any answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

In documentation (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator), is stated that you can use `output_types=None` as an argument. Did you try this or something else?

Comment: `output_types=None` is the default setting for it... you must use it, or `output_signature=` which is even more convoluted. Short answer yes, I tried...

Comment: Can you provide lines of the code where you are trying to use from_generator() and get some errors? 

There is also a warning "Warning: SOME ARGUMENTS ARE DEPRECATED: (output_shapes, output_types). They will be removed in a future version. Instructions for updating: Use output_signature instead" in the documentation.

Here you have a nice solution, maybe it will inspire you for your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52443273/how-do-you-send-arguments-to-a-generator-function-using-tf-data-dataset-from-gen